# Format Horizontal Styling of DataTable from PrimeNG to Vertical Styling

Tags: angular, primeng, vertical-alignment, primeng-datatable

I use PrimeNG beta 17 with Angular 2 and and have come by a situation where I want to change the Horizontal Layout of DataTable to Vertical layout as illustrated below:

By Default:
Horizontal Datatable Layout
[image]

My requirement:
Vertical DataTable Layout
[image: Vertical DataTable Layout]

So, can anybody hint me a way to do that using PrimeNG esp. using DataTable

Thanks.

Comment: PrimeFaces != PrimeNG !!!

Comment: Just like with the PrimeFaces datatable and mostly other datatable... transpose your data